# Getting a unique value from an aggregated result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got an aggregated query that checks if I have more than one record matching certain conditions.

```
  SELECT RegardingObjectId, COUNT(*) FROM [CRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[AsyncOperationBase] a
  where WorkflowActivationId IN ('55D9A3CF-4BB7-E311-B56B-0050569512FE',
  '1BF5B3B9-0CAE-E211-AEB5-0050569512FE',
  'EB231B79-84A4-E211-97E9-0050569512FE',
  'F0DDF5AE-83A3-E211-97E9-0050569512FE',
  '9C34F416-F99A-464E-8309-D3B56686FE58')
  and StatusCode = 10
      group by RegardingObjectId
  having COUNT(*) > 1
```

That's nice, but then there is one field in `AsyncOperationBase` that will be unique. Say `count(*)` = 3, well, `AsyncOperationBaseId` in `AsyncOperationBase` will have 3 different values since `AsyncOperationBase` is the table's primary key.

To be honest, I would not even know what terms and expressions to Google to find a solution.

If anyone has a solution and also, is there any words to describe what I'm looking for ? Perhaps BI people are often faced with such a requirement or something...

I could do it with an SSRS report where the report would visually do the grouping then I could expand each grouped row to get the `AsyncOperationBaseId` value, but simply through SQL, I can't seem to find a way out...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from [CRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[AsyncOperationBase]
where RegardingObjectId in
(
   SELECT RegardingObjectId
   FROM [CRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[AsyncOperationBase] a
   where WorkflowActivationId IN 
   (
     '55D9A3CF-4BB7-E311-B56B-0050569512FE',
     '1BF5B3B9-0CAE-E211-AEB5-0050569512FE',
     'EB231B79-84A4-E211-97E9-0050569512FE',
     'F0DDF5AE-83A3-E211-97E9-0050569512FE',
     '9C34F416-F99A-464E-8309-D3B56686FE58'
   )
   and StatusCode = 10
   group by RegardingObjectId
   having COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. If the query above returns 10 rows, and COUNT(*) = 2, that means I really have 20 rows. Now what I want is the unique ID (primary key) of all these 20 rows.

Comment: Now, that seems to do it. :) But I had to add the same condition on the topmost SELECT though.